# Проблема с вызовом WebView из Service

Tags: android, java, webview, service

Всем доброго времени суток.

Создал 2 сервиса, 1-й с mediaPlayer и 2-й с webView. Оба прописаны в манифесте:

```
...
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="TestPlayRadio"></service>
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="TestWebView"></service>
...
```

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии кнопки вызывались эти 2 сервиса играло радио и вызвался сайт.

```
public class MainTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);
        final Button on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                startService(new Intent(MainTestActivity.this, TestPlayRadio.class));

                Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Service started.");

                startService(new Intent(MainTestActivity.this, TestWebView.class));

                Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Service started.");
            }
        });
   ...
```

MediaPlayer - играет. А вот WebView, даже если без радио, ну никак не отображается в заданном окошке... Может быть я что-то не так прописал?

```
public class TestWebView extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void view(Activity v) {

        WebView wv;

        wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www...");
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setSavePassword(true);
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте права на интернет в манифесте

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
   ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Permission на доступ к интернету есть 8*( мб практикуется какой нибудь другой способ?

Comment: практикуется - вынести музыку в отдельный поток

Comment: так же проверь адрес, который грузишь, может такого сайта нету

Comment: Тоесть, музыка в отдельном потоке? Она и так как отдельный сервис. И сайт работает 100% 
В мейне есть еще 1н webView - рабочий, они могут как-то конфликтовать ?

Comment: отдельный сервис - это не отдельный поток, это UI-thread